# Problem with bst file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm using nar.bst here (http://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/ftp/nar.bst). However when I include my bibliography in the following manner :-

```
\bibliographystyle{nar}
\bibliography{main}
```

However the resulting bbl file seems to have some unclosed braces. For example, I get the following bibitem where the \bf brace is unclosed.

```
\bibitem{chang2013temporal}
Chang, K.~N., Zhong, S., Weirauch, M.~T., Hon, G., Pelizzola, M., Li, H.,
Huang, S.-s.~C., Schmitz, R.~J., Urich, M.~A., Kuo, D., et al. (2013)
{\em Elife} {\bf 2.
```

which is generated from the bibtex

```
@article{chang2013temporal,
  title={Temporal transcriptional response to ethylene gas drives growth                hormone cross-regulation in Arabidopsis},
  author={Chang, Katherine Noelani and Zhong, Shan and Weirauch, Matthew T and Hon, Gary and Pelizzola, Mattia and Li, Hai and Huang, Shao-shan Carol and Schmitz, Robert J and Urich, Mark A and Kuo, Dwight and others},
  journal={Elife},
  volume={2},
  year={2013},
  publisher={eLife Sciences Publications Limited}
}
```

I *think* (but not sure at all) that the function

```
format.vol.num.pages
```

is the culprit but not sure how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated :)

PS :- Fixing the open braces which seem to only happen when \bf is present fixes the problem.

Edit (Edit 3 -- removed NAR cls -- that doesn't change anything for me): Minimal example below. Compiling using pdflatex and then running bibtex gives the wrongly formatted bibitem (as shown above) in the bbl file

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Sample}

\author{Sample}

\maketitle

Example~\cite{chang2013temporal}

\bibliographystyle{nar}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

I have the @article in the file main.bib and name the MWE as main.tex. Then I run pdflatex main.tex 2 times and after that bibtex main to get main.bbl which has the wrong formatting.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem with a MWE: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{cite} \begin{document}  \nocite{*}\bibliographystyle{nar} 
\bibliography{main} \end{document}`. Please provide a *complete, but minimal* example that shows the problem.

Comment: I've added the minimal example. NAR is the the NAR style file given here (http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/nar/for_authors/nar-latex2010.zip)

Comment: Since I don't have the `NAR` document class, I used `article` in your MWE and got the correct formatting: `\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{chang2013temporal}
Chang, K.~N., Zhong, S., Weirauch, M.~T., Hon, G., Pelizzola, M., Li, H.,
  Huang, S.-s.~C., Schmitz, R.~J., Urich, M.~A., Kuo, D., et al. (2013)
Temporal transcriptional response to ethylene gas drives growth hormone
  cross-regulation in Arabidopsis.
{\em Elife,} {\bf 2}.

\end{thebibliography}` Do you have a link to `NAR.cls` to test if the problem comes from there? (It's a remote possibility, but I want to make sure).

Comment: I downloaded NAR:cls and related files from http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/nar/for_authors/nar-latex2010.zip and after using your MWE *as is* I couldn't reproduce the problem you mention; the .bbl gets correctly formatted.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. So, I'm putting the @article in the file main.bib and naming the MWE as main.tex. Then I run pdflatex main.tex 2 times and after that bibtex main to get main.bbl. Is that what you're doing as well?

Comment: You need to run pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex twice more.

Comment: @cfr that doesn't change anything -- I still get the wrong formatting...

Comment: Also seems like the NAR cls doesn't change anything. article document class gives the same problem for me. My bibtex version is 0.99d and pdflatex is 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15

Comment: Do you get the wrong formatting with the MWE?

Comment: @cfr Yeah       15char

Comment: I confirm that the MWE as it is works properly (so not able to reproduce the problem) to with the bst file provided by the link.  I would suggest to remove the wrongly created bbl and then run again the  procedure indicated by @cfr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

The most recent version of `nar.bst` has now been updated on CTAN (which had previously had on older version.)  Up-to-date TL 2015 and MikTeX should now have this version. If you are running an older version of TL, use the version on CTAN.

*Original answer*

The version of `nar.bst` that comes with TL (as of 2015) is outdated.  The most recent version is [here](http://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/ftp/nar.bst), which is the link in the original question.  This version fixes the problem and so no modification of the `.bst.` is needed. This explains why others were unable to reproduce the error.  I've emailed the author of the `.bst` file to ask him to put an updated version on CTAN.

So the lesson to be learned is to make sure that you are using up-to-date copies AND your system is actually finding them.

There are various ways to see which copy of a file TeX is finding, but by far the simplest is to use `kpsewhich` from the command line. Executing the command:

```
kpsewhich nar.bst
```

will tell you exactly which file is being used.  On a standard TL system it will return: (modulo your year.)

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/beebe/nar.bst
```

TeX Live in particular is quite picky about where `.bst` files are to be found, so when you download the latest copy and want it to be found, it should be placed in:

```
<path-to-local-texmf>/texmf/bibtex/bst/
```

where `<path-to-local-texmf>` will vary depending on your system.  If you don't know where it is, you can find the path to it by issuing the following command:

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
```

Comment: You could have also changed `\bf` into `\bfseries`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I'm a minimalist. :)  And there are other instances of it in the `.bst` file that would also need to be changed.

Comment: Hmm seems like it introduced a bug -- this different e.g. gives me the same error now @article{shytaj2013cure,
  title={A cure for AIDS: a matter of timing},
  author={Shytaj, Iart Luca and Savarino, Andrea},
  journal={Retrovirology},
  volume={10},
  number={1},
  pages={145},
  year={2013},
  publisher={BioMed Central Ltd}
}

Comment: @Opt Let me check.  It was late last night and I didn't test extensively. Also, I realized that I was working using the TeX Live version of the `.bst` which is a bit older.  Let me check with the most recent copy.

Comment: @opt I've made a chat room for us. Can we chat about this? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26745/chat-alan-and-opt

Comment: @AlanMunn sure     15 char